# Heroku Node deployment "internal server error"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, heroku, deployment

I have my app deployed to heroku. Once I go to the user signup page and enter my credentials the site immediately crashes, displaying `internal server error` in the browser, and giving me this in the `heroku logs`.

I'm not sure what might be the issue so I don't know which code to give? I don't think it has to do with MySQL but considering it's mentioned in the error report, it might be? Either way here is my `connection.js`:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
let connection;

if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL) {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
} else {
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'trythis_db'
    });
};

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('mysql is connected');
    };
});


module.exports = connection;
```

This is my error code:

```
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486756+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486150+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /signup 302 287.664 ms - 46
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486758+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486758+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486759+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486760+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486761+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486762+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486763+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486763+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486765+00:00 app[web.1]:     at MySQLStore.set (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/lib/index.js:192:19)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Session.save (/app/node_modules/express-session/session/session.js:72:25)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Session.save (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:381:15)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486767+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.end (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:330:21)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.486768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.redirect (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:947:10)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638706+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638708+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638709+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638710+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638710+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638711+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638712+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638713+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638713+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638714+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638802+00:00 app[web.1]:     at session (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:460:11)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at MySQLStore.get (/app/node_modules/express-mysql-session/lib/index.js:130:19)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638803+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2017-12-04T04:58:51.638804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with another library related to storing sessions in MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the error (`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`) says that the app is trying to connect to localhost even when it is hosted online, where it should try to connect to the online database. You need to figure out what's wrong in the `if-else` statements, since, the `else` loop is being executed, which, I guess, is for your local environment.

Comment: I had `console.log` in my if-else statement to confirm that I wasn't connecting to the localhost and the test passed so it isn't anything wrong with that...

Comment: Did you try to put the `console` statement in the `JAWSDB_URL` `if-else` statement?

Comment: Also, see if your JAWSDB_URL is set correctly. [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb#troubleshooting) might help.

Comment: yes i did. and I confirmed that my JAWSDB_URL is set correctly as well...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `JAWSDB_URL` under project config variables.

(Heroku project -> settings -> config variables -> reveal variables -> your `var`)

Comment: JAWSDB_URL is in my project config variables

Comment: Checked and confirmed. I’m not sure it’s a database thing because even getting the homepage will give me an internal server error, and calling the homepage doesn’t require querying the database at all

Comment: Then I think the problem is with your server configuration. Once post your server code.